# How to check if music is playing with Last FM API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, last.fm

I'm doing a React app where I'm using Last FM API. App shows current track if music is playing or if it's not it shows last listened track. At this point everything works just fine.
My problem is I want to show if I'm currently listening or not, but just don't know how. I tried to scroll through documentation but didn't really find anything helpful.

I'm fetching data from here:
[https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=${userName}&api_key=${apiKey}&format=json](https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=$%7BuserName%7D&api_key=$%7BapiKey%7D&format=json)

```
const track = scrobbles?.recenttracks?.track;

const [
    { name: songName, artist: { '#text': artistName } = {}} 
= {}] = track;

    return (
        <div>
            <h1>playing</h1>
            <h3>{songName}</h3>
            <h3>{artistName}</h3>
        </div>
    )
```

scrobbles is variable where all of JSON data is stored. In JSON data there is nowplaying attribute inside track array which returns boolean value, I just don't know how to use that value.

I found this link which shows stored JSON data:
https://lastfm-docs.github.io/api-docs/user/getRecentTracks/

I'd like to have probably some kind of conditional statement around that h1 element which shows playing or not playing.

Any ideas how to do that? Thanks

Comment: Where is this "nowplaying attribute"? can you send a link for that information? documentation link of course

Comment: Here: https://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getRecentTracks , also in here below examples -> example response of a user currently scrobbling: https://lastfm-docs.github.io/api-docs/user/getRecentTracks/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found solution for this. This probably isn't best or most beautiful solution but it works.

```
const track = scrobbles?.recenttracks?.track

if (track.length > 0) {
        const trarray = track[0];
        if (trarray['@attr'] && trarray['@attr']['nowplaying']) {

            return (
                <div>
                    <h1>Playing</h1>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }



return (
    <div>
        <h1>Not playing</h1>
    </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The track that’s currently playing should have a

```
"@attr": {
    "nowplaying": "true"
},
```

attribute associated with it. Compare the sample output of `getRecentTracks` for scenarios when a track is currently scrobbling vs. when it’s not.

I’m not sure why “true” is a string, not a Boolean.

Comment: I think these "@attr" values appear in api url. So when track is scrobbling this attribute is added to api url like this: `https://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.getRecentTracks&user=${userName}&api_key=${apiKey}&format=json&nowplaying=true` . I just don't know how to use that information to create conditional statement or something similar to show if track is currently playing or not. EDIT: I thing nowplaying value is always true. If track is not scrobbling nowplaying doesn't appear at all..